# Visual Studio 2010: test runtime directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, output

In order to get a rather tedious third party library to work, I need my unit tests to be executed in a specific, prepared directory with a large set of resource files there (~ 500MB). The reason for this is that aforesaid third party library will only work when all resources, libraries and executables of my program are located in that same directory.

When running Visual Studio 2010 unit tests, however, the test runner always creates a new directory (e.g. "default[1]") per test run. How can I get it to always use the same, fixed directory?

Comment: Can you use [mocks](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for the third party stuff?

Comment: I have in other tests, but this one is sort of a regression test to cover the whole functionality. So no, I would rather avoid mocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at the visual studio [test settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

There are many options from running custom scripts, to specifying files to be copied when unit tests are run.

I'm not sure, but you *might* be able to specify the directory you want to run the unit tests in.

Comment: I have, yes. You can switch to "User-defined scheme" in the "General" view, but that doesn't get beyond the "[1]", "[2]", etc. being appended to the folder name.

Comment: Since the file size of the prepared resources is rather large, I would like to refrain from copying it on every test run.